# Error connecting to WebSocket when installing rancher v2.4.4 on a server hosting cyberpanel

Tags: rancher, cyber-panel

I get this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqChG.png) when tring to install Rancher on a server hosts Cyberpanel.
with :

```
  docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped \
  -p 880:80 -p 8443:443 \
  rancher/rancher:latest \
  --acme-domain rancher.domain.com
```

Its the rancher/rancher:latest image mapping ports and reverse proxy with openlitespeed.

Can anyone familiar with this issue help out, please.

I'm not sure if it's a bug or bot so to be safe I posted an 'issue' on GitHub yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

```
nginx.org/websocket-services: rancher
```

Just add the above in annotation of ingress in cattle-system namespace to fix it. I verified it, and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just had to install rancher with extra annotations, especially **"nginx.org/websocket-services" : rancher**

Whether it will work for you depends which ingress controller you do have in your cluster. That one clearly works for nginx only.

```
helm upgrade --install rancher rancher/rancher \
--set debug=true \
--set tls=ingress \
--set hostname=your.domain.com  \
--set ingress.enabled=true \
--set ingress.tls.source=letsEncrypt \
--set ingress.extraAnnotations.'kubernetes\.io/ingress\.class'='nginx' \    
--set ingress.extraAnnotations.'nginx\.org/websocket-services'='rancher' \
--set "extraEnv[0].name=CATTLE_FEATURES,extraEnv[0].value=fleet=false"  \
--set "letsEncrypt.email=your.email@xxx.com" \
--set letsEncrypt.ingress.class=nginx \
--set letsEncrypt.environment=staging
```